# JavaFX WebView won't show

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I am having trouble with JavaFX, I only get an empty window when I try to load a web view. Any ideas?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * Created by poa on 15.04.2014.
 */
public class GUI extends Application{

    private Scene scene;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        final WebView browser = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn, browser);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        stage.show();
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't load anything into the WebView, so there is nothing to see in it.

Because you put the web view and the button in a stack pane, which stacks nodes one on top of the other, the empty web view is on top of the button, so you can't see the button.